# UI-Bootstrap pagination doesn't work when I upgrade to 1.2.5

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I implemented pagination using ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js. Now when I upgrade to 
ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js, the pagination doesn't work.

Is there any example for pagination using ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js.
With the current implementation, I am using like below

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"  
    max-size="5" boundary-links="true"  
    items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
</pagination>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration is not so far from being over.

From the docs

> Since version 0.14.0 we started to prefix all our components. If you are upgrading from ui-bootstrap 0.13.4 or earlier, check our [migration guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes)

The directive name you are looking for is `uib-pagination`.

Check out the syntax [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.2.5/#/pagination)

So, your new markup (for version 1.2.5) would look something like this

```
<uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"  
    max-size="5" boundary-links="true"  
    items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
</uib-pagination>
```

Comment: then please click the green V to accept this answer

Comment: Did something change to display the dropdown  in 1.2.5. to select the number of records per page(5,10,15 ..so on) to display on the page. It is not working.Is there any example for the reference.

Comment: check the migration guide, they changed most directive names and even services names, if still in doubt just use the examples from the site